# how to set crosstab() output to array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

In R, I can take a df and get a list of frequency tables for each sample/group by doing the following:

```
df <- data.frame(cell = c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8"),
                 layer = c("L1", "L1", "L2", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L3", "L4", "L4", "L3"),
                 sample = c("1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1"))
> df
   cell layer sample
1    c1    L1      1
2    c1    L1      2
3    c1    L2      2
4    c2    L1      1
5    c3    L2      1
6    c4    L3      2
7    c5    L3      2
8    c6    L4      2
9    c7    L4      1
10   c8    L3      1

tab <- table(df)
> tab
, , sample = 1

    layer
cell L1 L2 L3 L4
  c1  1  0  0  0
  c2  1  0  0  0
  c3  0  1  0  0
  c4  0  0  0  0
  c5  0  0  0  0
  c6  0  0  0  0
  c7  0  0  0  1
  c8  0  0  1  0

, , sample = 2

    layer
cell L1 L2 L3 L4
  c1  1  1  0  0
  c2  0  0  0  0
  c3  0  0  0  0
  c4  0  0  1  0
  c5  0  0  1  0
  c6  0  0  0  1
  c7  0  0  0  0
  c8  0  0  0  0
```

and I can select the sample I want by `tab[,,1]`. How can I do this in python?

I found the function crosstab()

```
xtab = pd.crosstab(index=df["cell"], columns=[df["sample"],df["layer"]])
```

but i don't know how to convert it to an array afterwards... i'm wondering if there's a way to `df.groupby("samples")` then create frequency matrix of cell x layer, for each sample?
Desired output something like:

```
[1]
     L1 L2 L3 L4
  c1  1  0  0  0
  c2  1  0  0  0
  c3  0  1  0  0
  c4  0  0  0  0
  c5  0  0  0  0
  c6  0  0  0  0
  c7  0  0  0  1
  c8  0  0  1  0

[2]
     L1 L2 L3 L4
  c1  1  1  0  0
  c2  0  0  0  0
  c3  0  0  0  0
  c4  0  0  1  0
  c5  0  0  1  0
  c6  0  0  0  1
  c7  0  0  0  0
  c8  0  0  0  0
```

where I get frequency arrays for each sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pandas` you can do `groupby` with `pd.crosstab`

```
d = {x : pd.crosstab(y['cell'],y['layer']) for x , y in df.groupby('sample')}

d[1]
layer  L1  L2  L3  L4
cell                 
c1      1   0   0   0
c2      1   0   0   0
c3      0   1   0   0
c7      0   0   0   1
c8      0   0   1   0
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns a dataframe object. is there a way to convert this to a numpy array/matrix?

Comment: @kas d = {x : pd.crosstab(y['cell'],y['layer']).values for x , y in df.groupby('sample')}
 ?

Comment: yes, perfect! that what i was looking for, thank you!